# Is there a better way to reconstruct a data from hundreds of millions of entries spread over a long period of time?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-11

(first of all - apologies for the title but I couldn't come up with a better one)

Here is my problem - I have a table with 4 columns - `entity::INT`, `entry::TEXT`, `state::INT` and `day::INT`.

There could be anywhere from 50 to 1,000 `entities`. Each `entity` can have over 100 million `entries`. Each `entry` can have one or more `states`, which changes if the data stored in the entry has changed but only one `state` can be written for any particular `day`. The `day` starts at one and is incremented each day.

Example:

```
entity | entry  | state     | day
-------------------------------------
1      | ABC123 | 1         | 1
1      | ABC124 | 2         | 1
1      | ABC125 | 3         | 1
...
1      | ABC999 | 999       | 1
2      | BCD123 | 1000      | 1
...
1      | ABC123 | 1001      | 2
2      | BCD123 | 1002      | 3
```

The index is set to `(entity, day, state)`.

What I want to achieve is to efficiently *select the most current state of each entry on day N.*

Currently, every week I write all the entries with their latest `state` to the table so to minimize the number of days that we need to scan, however, given the total number of `entries` (worst case scenario - 1,000 entities times 100,000,000 entries is a lot of rows to write each week) the table is slowly but surely bloats and everything becomes really slow.

I need to be able to stop writing this "full" version weekly and instead have a setup that will still be fast enough to achieve that. I considered to use `DISTINCT ON` with a different index set to `(entity, entry, day DESC, state)` so that I could:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (entity, entry) entry, state
FROM table
WHERE entity = <entity> AND day <= <day>
ORDER BY entity, entry, day DESC, state;
```

Would that be the most efficient way to do it or there are better ways? Or `entry` possibly having hundreds of millions of unique values makes it a poor choice for the second column in the index and the performance will eventually come to a halt?

Comment: Is there a possibility to redesign the schema, e.g. split this table, write to additional tables via a trigger, etc?

Comment: I know that this does not answer your question, but have you considered using TimescaleDB for this?

Comment: @IMSoP sure can redesign if there is a better approach.

Comment: @MikeOrganek cannot do, stuck with PG 11

Comment: Timescaledb is installed on PostGreSQL and compatible with v11. It essentially automatically creates new partitions in the tables for each time series and manages that for you.

Comment: You mention `version` and `state`. Which is it? (Please [edit] the question to fix.) You also mention to `select the most current state of each entry on day N.` But then show a query to do that for *one* entity. You also mention another table and I am not sure what we are working off now. Please clarify the setup and the question.

Comment: And is there a table "entry" holding *one* row for each existing entry? I.e., each existing (or relevant) distinct combination of `(entity, entry)`? That would help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to rank the entries by time an take the latest one. That's the same as ranking them in reverse time orse and taking the first one. And `ROW_NUMBER()` is one way to do that.

```
WITH
    ranked AS
(
    SELECT
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (
                PARTITION BY entity, entry
                    ORDER BY day DESC
            )
              AS entity_entry_rank
    FROM
        yourTable
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
     ranked
WHERE
    entity_entry_rank = 1
```

The day column can then become a timestamp, and you don't need to store a new copy every day.

The appropriate index would be `(entity, entry, timestamp)`

Also, it's common to have two tables. One with the history, one with the latest value. That makes use of the current value quicker, at a minor disk overhead.

(Apologies for errors or formating, I'm on my phone.)

Comment: I should have specified that, but the `day` is there because the entries are collected once per day in bulk so the time doesn't really matter. On a "normal" day, only rows for new entries are added or for the entries whose state has changed. In regards to two tables, the actual data belongs to the entity is already stored in a separate table. ```entry``` here is an external reference while ```state``` is an internal reference which is used to retrieve data from another table

Comment: @afonja - I'm not sure what exactly you're asking then. I think you should update your question to be much more specific and clear.  Either way, the pattern above is usually the best one for finding "the latest row", and/or having one table for the latest data and a separate one for the history (managed by an ETL pipeline and/or triggers). To cover all the options would fill a book, SO is really only suited to Specific questions rather than wide-ranging discussions.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT ON` is simple, and performance is great - for ***few*** rows per entry. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Not for ***many*** rows per entry, though.

> Each entity can have over 100 million entries

See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Assuming an `entry` table that holds *one* row for each existing entry (each  relevant distinct combination of `(entity, entry)`), this query is very efficient to get the *latest* state for a given day:

```sql
SELECT e.entity, e.entry, t.day, t.state
FROM   entry e
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT day, state
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  (entity, entry) = (e.entity, e.entry)
   AND    day <= <day>  -- given day
   ORDER  BY day DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) t ON true;
ORDER  BY e.entity, e.entry; -- optional
```

Use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` instead of the `LEFT JOIN` if you only want entries that have at least one row in `tbl`.

The perfect index for this is on `(entity, entry, day) INCLUDE (state)`.

If you have no table `entry`, consider creating one. (Typically, there should be one.) The rCTE techniques outlined in [the linked answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860) can also be used to create such a table.